# Error in building ruby 1.9.3 universal version with rvm

Tags: ruby, rvm, 32bit-64bit

I'm trying to build 32bit/64bit version of ruby with rvm with `sudo rvm install 1.9.3 --universal` command.

It failed, and the log file is as follows:

```
linking shared-object tcltklib.bundle
ld: in /usr/local/lib/libxml2.2.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386) for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [../../.ext/universal-darwin11.4.0/tcltklib.bundle] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ext/tk/all] Error 2
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

The message says libxml is built with 64bit, but tcltk that uses it is 32bit.
What might be wrong? How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried using this flags `--without-tk --without-tcl` ... ofcourse if you do not need **tk**.

other solution would be to recompile all your libraries with --universal too, but this might bet tedious work.